# Pick a color from the dropdown and set as background in angularjs1

Tags: angularjs

I want the program to select a color from the dropdown list and set as background color. I have written a code for it. I have used directives - ng-model, ng-style,ng-repeat.

```
<html ng-app="Swabhav.Color">
<head>
    <title>Color-pick</title>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-
 bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
/>
<script 
src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js">
 </script>


  </head>
  <body>
        <script>
                 var app = angular.module("Swabhav.Color", []); 
                 app.controller("dropdowncolor", ["$scope",function($scope) 
             {
                 $scope.colors = [{ name: "Red", hex: "#F21B1B" },
                                     { name: "Blue", hex: "#0099CC" }, 
                                     { name: "Green", hex: "#07BA16" },
                                     { name: "Yellow", hex: "#FFFF99"}];

                 }]);

                </script>

        <div ng-controller="dropdowncolor">
            <p>Select a color</p>

            <select ng-model="selectedcolor">
            <option ng-repeat="selectcolor in colors"  value="{{selectcolor.hex}}">
            your selected color is : {{selectcolor.name}}  
            <p ng-style="{'background-color':selectcolor.hex}"  ></p>
            </option>   

            </select>
            </div>

  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: What exactly you are stuck in you were able to get the dropdown value color and it is not assigned to background via ng-style or you are not even getting the selected color

Comment: I am unable to change the background color

Comment: Try this <p ng-style="{'background-color':{{selectcolor.hex}}}"  ></p>

Answer (score 0):

You can try like the below code, also check this working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zCnRbO34zZXYkLCQYQ3e?p=preview) link for your example scenario,

Templates:

```
    <select ng-model="selectedcolor" ng-options="color.name as color.name for color in backgroundColors">
    </select>
    <p ng-style="{'background-color': selectedcolor}">
      <br/>
      Your selected color is : {{selectedcolor}}  
      <br/><br/>
    </p>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.backgroundColors = [
    { name: "Red", hex: "#F21B1B" },
    { name: "Blue", hex: "#0099CC" }, 
    { name: "Green", hex: "#07BA16" },
    { name: "Yellow", hex: "#FFFF99"}];
```

Comment: i want the background color of the entire page changed to that color

Comment: you have to simply add the ng-style to your <body> tag instead of <p> tag. As I've updated in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zCnRbO34zZXYkLCQYQ3e?p=preview) you can have a look.

Comment: i don't understand, we are not using the parameter hex for color code, so how does the DOM come to know about which color to select..we have not used hex anywhere in the DOM elements

Comment: And keeping the ng-style in<body> tag doesn't work because, the <script > and <div > tags are already in <body >tag

Comment: hex code is not the only way to get color to background-color attribute of css. Of course it will accept the predefined color directly. And why didn't you check [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/zCnRbO34zZXYkLCQYQ3e?p=preview) updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zCnRbO34zZXYkLCQYQ3e?p=preview) which is working..

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is change your P tag like below

```
 <p ng-style="{background-color: '{{selectcolor.hex}}'}"></p>
```

Comment: Try with this 'background-color'